# Occasional issues switching between Chrome and iTerm2 on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, google-chrome, desktop, iterm2, alt-tab

I'm running an up-to-date macOS Mojave system.  I'm using iTerm2 (Build 3.2.8) in full-screen mode, and I'm also running some other application in full-screen mode on other desktops.

Occasionally, when switching from another full-screen application (usually Chrome) to iTerm2 using <kbd>⌘+Tab</kbd>, I'm brought to the Finder desktop (the one that I would have been brought to by clicking the Finder icon in the task bar).

It's worth noting that the menu at the top of the desktop that is displayed actually belongs to iTerm2, but that the desktop has no iTerm2 windows on it whatsoever. It therefore seems that I have successfully switched to the *correct application*, but ended up on the *wrong desktop*.

At that point, switching back and forth between Chrome and iTerm2 consistently switches between the full-screen Chrome application and the Finder desktop, but never brings me to the desktop containing the full-screen iTerm2 application.  The only way to then switch to iTerm2 is by manually clicking on its icon in the task bar, or by scrolling through the desktops using <kbd>Ctrl+ArrowKey</kbd>.

This is annoying since I often have to switch between Chrome and iTerm2, and I need to run both in full-screen mode due to having a small screen and imperfect vision.

I'm wondering whether this is a known issue, whether it's fixable, and what part of the system or which application is misbehaving (i.e. where to send the bug report).

Comment: Does Finder definitely show as the from-most app on the menu bar [if you don't touch anything else, of course]?

Comment: @Tetsujin No, the menu at the top of the screen, after switching to iTerm2 (but ending up on the wrong desktop) belongs to iTerm2. I had not actually spotted this before. That desktop contains no open iTerm2 windows, however.

Comment: Is iTerm specifically locked to a given Space, or is it also full-screened? [There are many reasons I never use fullscreen, & this lack of predictability is one of them - see this for my preferred working method to avoid using fullscreen. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275

Comment: @Tetsujin iTerm2 is not assigned to any specific desktop. I'm using iTerm2 in full-screen mode (having clicked the full-screen button at the top left of its window). I'll have a look at your answer on the AskDifferent site to see if that helps, but it would be good to also resolve this issue here.

Comment: Same issue here, full-screen iterm2 and some other full-screen stuff.  Occasionally (randomly?) I cmd-tab back to iterm2 but end up on the "Desktop 1" space.  I've tried all combinations of "cmd-tab switches to most recent" and disabled/enabled the "swipe" animations between full-screen apps, but the occasional glitches with iterm2 persist.  My other full-screen apps include Firefox, Emacs, and Preview.